# view.js issue at Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I am using this plugin http://finegoodsmarket.com/view/ It's great but only at Chrome I have issue with hidden background-color when first time clicking on an image. Here is the link http://layot.prestatrend.com/?p=26#comments Seems it's because of webkit transitions I am using. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine in my browser. Check for any errors in the js console. Might get some Idea.